# Как поправить код на javaScript + jQuery

Tags: jquery

доброго времени суток! написал я тут "типа" код:

```
 var n = 0;
    var s = $('#next').click(function(){
     s = n++;
      if (s < 15){       
        var mass = ['#li_1','#li_2','#li_3','#li_4','#li_5','#li_6','#li_7','#li_8','#li_9','#li_10','#li_11','#li_12','#li_13','#li_14','#li_15','#li_16','#li_17','#li_18','#li_19','#li_20'];
        var li = mass[s];
        $(li).hide();
        var sh = s+5; 
        var li2 = mass[sh];
        $(li2).show();
        return s;
    } 
    else {s = 15; return s;}  
});

    s = $('#previous').click(function(){
     s = n--;
      if (s > 0){
        var mass = ['#li_1','#li_2','#li_3','#li_4','#li_5','#li_6','#li_7','#li_8','#li_9','#li_10','#li_11','#li_12','#li_13','#li_14','#li_15','#li_16','#li_17','#li_18','#li_19','#li_20'];
        var li = mass[s];
        $(li).show();
        var sh = s+5; 
        var li2 = mass[sh];
        $(li2).hide();
        return s;
    }
    else {s = 0; return s;}
});
```

это два массива с id фотографий, которые, в свою очередь, в виде списка в DIV'е
и вот проблема, все работает, но при нажатии на кнопку "previous" или "next" фотографии не сразу меняются а только со второго или третьего нажатия. Как доработать???

Comment: @MojoHed, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: `var s = n--;`f (s >= 0){` ... А если меньше ?

Comment: нет, он скрывает фото, но тоже со второго или третьего клика.

Comment: я говорю у вас условие недописанное

Comment: не помогает. все также

Comment: сделайте jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
function(s){
```

тут напишите другое имя переменной. Или создайте еще 10 переменных с таким именем.

```
['#li_1','#li_2','#li_3','#li_4','#li_5','#li_6','#li_7','#li_8','#li_9','#li_10','#li_11','#li_12','#li_13','#li_14','#li_15','#li_16','#li_17','#li_18','#li_19','#li_20`'];
```

почему так мало? Пишите 100 таких айди.